# Problem grouping rows with different indexes with python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an initial file 'data_points_20180101.txt' with data in the following format:

```
Latitude: 30°02′59″S   -30.04982864
Longitude: 51°12′05″W   -51.20150245
Distance: 2.2959 km  Bearing: 137.352°
Latitude: 30°04′03″S   -30.06761588
Longitude: 51°14′23″W   -51.23976111
Distance: 4.2397 km  Bearing: 210.121°
Latitude: 30°03′21″S   -30.05596474
Longitude: 51°10′22″W   -51.17286827
Distance: 4.9213 km  Bearing: 118.814°

(...)
```

I need a DataFrame with only the second values of latitude and longitude.

With the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_fwf('data_points_20180101.txt', colspecs=[(0,9),(10,21),(21,38)], header=None)
df = df[~df[0].str.contains('Distance:')]
df = df.drop(columns=[1])
df = df.pivot(columns=0, values=2)
```

I changed my data to this format:

```
    Latitude    Longitude
0   -30.04982864    NaN
1   NaN     -51.20150245
3   -30.06761588    NaN
4   NaN     -51.23976111
6   -30.05596474    NaN
...     ...     ...
2988    NaN     -51.18562751
2990    -30.01986809    NaN
2991    NaN     -51.18678828
2993    -30.00657367    NaN
2994    NaN     -51.25739042
```

But in this format, the latitude/longitude pairs are not at the same row. How can I substitute the NaN values at each row by the correct value from the next row, for example:

```
    Latitude   Longitude
0   -30.04982864   -51.20150245
1   -30.06761588   -51.23976111
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['Longitude'] = df['Longitude'].bfill()
df = df.dropna()
```

Or a one-liner:

```
df = df.assign(Longitude=df.Longitude.bfill()).dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the structure of the table is exactly like this, you can simply load your dataset into two tables alternating rows:

```
df_lat = df.iloc[::2, :]
df_lon = df.iloc[1::2, :]
```

then *concat* them along *axis=1*. With a proper column naming you will get what you want.